# Stop webBrowser control if document does not complete

Tags: c#, navigation, browser

I am using a C# webBrowser control using the `DocumentCompleted` -

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
```

I am then navigating -

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("myUrl")
```

However if the request to that server hangs, i.e. the page does not complete after say 10 seconds, how could I implement the `webBrowser1.Stop();`?

I did try to implement a count, that if it got to 20 i.e. the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` went into an infinite loop (the page would not complete) then stop however not sure if this is the most straightforward way of doing htis?

Answer (score 0):

This might be in really bad practice so I apologize but you could use a boolean control with a timer to check whether or not the document has completed and if it hasn't, close the webBrowser.

First of all add a timer(assuming its called Timer1) to your form, setting interval to 1000 and create an int and bool control.

```
     int timeLeft;
     bool hasCompleted = false;
```

Run your URL as normal and start your timer

```
     webBrowser1.Navigate("myUrl");
     timeLeft = 10;
     Timer1.Start();
```

And your timer should look like this;

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(timeLeft > 0) {
            timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
        }
        if(timeLeft = 0 && !hasCompleted)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            webBrowser1.Stop();
        }
        else{
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

  private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
        hasCompleted = true;
        //your code
}
```

Comment: the problem i see with this method is what if webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted doesnt ever actually complete?

Comment: Why would it not complete? I've tested this and it will stop the web browser if the browser doesn't complete. If it does complete, I used google.com as an example, then just the timer stops and the web browser stays open.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to achieve this using the timer.
I just added a timer and set the interval.

Here is the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new 
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler( webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        LoadBrowser();
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = "Cancelled";            
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Page Loaded succesfully");
        }
    }

    private void LoadBrowser()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }



}
```